# Script Task to change the data provider in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have 2 different sources to be loaded in Datawarehouse with a condition.
1st source is flat file and the second source is SQL database. Condition is the SSIS package should check the flag value in a table, If the value is 0, it should process the flat file and if the value is 1, then it should process the data from SQL source. I know this can be done in built in task but it must be done in Script task by dynamically changing the connection type (data provider) based on the flag value. Anybody who is well versed in .NET, Please help on this. Kindly let me know if something is not clear

Thanks.

Comment: Different sources have completely different metadata. A flat file has 0 type information. A database has *a lot*. You can't replace one with the other without forcing the entire flow to update. Use a Union operator instead to combine the two sources, and an expression that enables/disables each of the two sources according to a variable's value.

Comment: Second to @PanagiotisKanavos. You can fetch a flag value and store it in a variable, then do a conditional processing switching between 2 DataFlows.

Comment: "changing the connection type"?   You can't.   You can't create a flat file connection and dynamically change it to a database connection or vice-versa.   I would do it the way @Ferdipux suggested.   Unless you're talking about doing the entire import dynamically in a single script task, which is also an option.

Comment: Downvotes are only allowed by people that do know about SSIS and *have* used expressions to dynamically change behavior. And deployed it. And debugged it. Only they know how fun it is to write an IIF expression without editor support

Comment: Thanks PanagiotisKanavos, Ferdipux, Tab Alleman.

Comment: Ferdipux, I agree we can do it by the way you mentioned but i want to achieve this in script task

Comment: PanagiotisKanavos, will it be possible to change the connection Type dynamically at run time in script task? BTW, can u please explain more about achieving this with union operator as u mentioned in 1st post?